# React + Rails CORS issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, cors, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an error every time my frontend project tries to do a request to the backend. For some reason it gets blocked by CORS every time i try to do a request, i've configured CORS already and i honestly have no clue what else i have to do. I'm using the rack-cors gem and i'm hosting both the frontend and the backend in heroku.

[chrome error on requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kendy.png)

here is my cors.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "https://vlipo.herokuapp.com"
    resource "*", headers: :any, methods: :any, credentials: true
  end
end
```

obviously the backend is under https://vlipo-backend.herokuapp.com and the frontend in https://vlipo.herokuapp.com

If it is worthy to know, i'm using react for the frontend, my ruby version is 2.6.6 and my rails version 6.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It complains that Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value is too broad: it's set to the wildcard * which means that everyone can make a request to your server. There are two ways of solving this problem

- Either set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to something like **[localhost:3000]** instead of the wildcard, so you client (running on **localhost:3000**) could request the server.
- Or set **withCredentials=false** mode on your client side. I usually use axios and and do something like this

---

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development';
```

---

You can check [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) on how to do it in case if you don't use axios.

Comment: What do i do in case i need withCredentials set as true in order to receive cookies from the backend?

Comment: Then you're left with only the first option, I guess...

Comment: Tried it and worked as a charm! Thanks for the help